# Binding volume with 'withFileSystemBind' -> Permission Denied

Tags: testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

i bind a volume to my GenericContainer as follows:

```
@Container    
public GenericContainer ap = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("myImage:latest"))
                                     .withExposedPorts(AP_PORT)
                                     .withEnv("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", "integrationtest")
                                     .withFileSystemBind("/home/user/tmp/rdf4jRepos/", "/mnt/spring/", BindMode.READ_WRITE)
                                     .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log))
                                     .waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/actuator/health"));
```

But i've a permission denied problem.
I added the following into the spring-boot app, that runs in the GenericContainer:
(rdfRepositoryHome = /mnt/spring)

```
File repoHome = new File(rdfRepositoryHome);
System.out.println( "getAbsolutePath: " + repoHome.getAbsolutePath());
File f2 = new File(repoHome, "testRepo");
System.out.println( "repoHome.isDirectory(): " + repoHome.isDirectory() );
System.out.println( "Execute: " + repoHome.canExecute() );
System.out.println( "Write: " + repoHome.canWrite() );
System.out.println( "READ: " + repoHome.canRead() );
```

output:

```
2021-08-04 16:11:31.566  INFO 326439 --- [tream-274971679] d.f.i.s.p.a.i.ITReadProfile              : STDOUT: getAbsolutePath: /mnt/spring
2021-08-04 16:11:31.567  INFO 326439 --- [tream-274971679] d.f.i.s.p.a.i.ITReadProfile              : STDOUT: repoHome.isDirectory(): true
2021-08-04 16:11:31.567  INFO 326439 --- [tream-274971679] d.f.i.s.p.a.i.ITReadProfile              : STDOUT: Execute: true
2021-08-04 16:11:31.567  INFO 326439 --- [tream-274971679] d.f.i.s.p.a.i.ITReadProfile              : STDOUT: Write: false
2021-08-04 16:11:31.567  INFO 326439 --- [tream-274971679] d.f.i.s.p.a.i.ITReadProfile              : STDOUT: READ: true
```

How can i bind a volume, that is writable?

Thanks

**Update 19.08.2021:**
I added a test to another project, that is public available:

Running on image:
maven:3.6.1-jdk-11

1. [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/linkedopenactors/loa-suite/-/blob/feature/testcontainer/.gitlab-ci.yml)
2. [TestCase](https://gitlab.com/linkedopenactors/loa-suite/-/blob/feature/testcontainer/integrationtests/src/test/java/org/linkedopenactors/code/integrationtests/ITLastSync.java)
3. [Dockerfile](https://gitlab.com/linkedopenactors/loa-suite/-/blob/feature/testcontainer/loa-app/loa-app-spring-boot/Dockerfile):
4. [Test Job line 117](https://gitlab.com/linkedopenactors/loa-suite/-/jobs/1517911083#L117)
5. [Test Job line 1800](https://gitlab.com/linkedopenactors/loa-suite/-/jobs/1517911083#L1800)

**Update 30.8.2021:**
The problem should be reproducable (independent from gitlab ci and DinD!) with

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/linkedopenactors/loa-suite.git
git checkout feature/testcontainer
cd loa-suite/
mvn clean install -DskipTests
cd integrationtests/
mvn -Dit.test=ITLastSync verify
```

Comment: On which OS are you running and what kind of Docker setup are you using?

Comment: @KevinWittek i added an update ^ .

Comment: It is very likely that this issue is related to the Gitlab-CI and DinD setup. Does it work when run locally?

Comment: @KevinWittek see "Update 30.8.2021" above

Comment: Please consider creating a simple reproducer:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java-repro

Comment: @KevinWittek see https://github.com/naturzukunft/testcontainer_problem

Comment: Note that this Docker command would also fail, so I struggle to see the Testcontainers specific problem here.
`docker run -ti --rm -v /tmp/dockerVolumes/:/mnt/spring/ -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test registry.gitlab.com/linkedopenactors/loa-suite:feature-testcontainer`
What would be the working Docker command?

Comment: GH discussion: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/discussions/4462